# Un able to print the value for the label in cell in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm unable to print the desired value in text format in the cell. Only the 1st eventname value is printed and not the rest which are in sub dictionary of it dictionary is placed in an array. I have a problem with the image as well. The images are null at the backend then it should load the placeholder in case. Here is the code I have written. There is no error in the fetching of JSON. I have debugged but I don't think there is an error with the JSON:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayNGOdetails.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let courseTitle = arrayNGOdetails[indexPath .row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCellEventMilesocdetails
    cell.milename.text = courseTitle.eventname
    cell.miledescription.text = courseTitle.studentclass
    cell.mileamount.text = courseTitle.studentfees
    return cell
}
```

Comment: func loaddata()
    {
//        if let idevent = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "idevent")
//        {
    let url = URL(string: "http://fundedindia.org/funded/event_details.php?eventid=\(temp.eventid!)")

Comment: Don't post updates in comments. [Edit] your question as needed.